# Как посчитать количество уникальных значений в списке в заданном столбце

Tags: python

Имеется большой список значений, в первом столбце которого количество элементов относительно невелико:

```
big_data_list = [
    ['google', 'cpc', 925],
    ['yandex', 'organic', 790],
    ['market', 'cpc', 465],
    ['google', 'organic', 413],
    ['google', 'cpc', 398],
    ['direct', 'none', 115],
    ['yandex', 'cpc', 43]
]
```

Необходимо посчитать количество уникальных значений канала в листе big_data_list (второй столбец)

Мой вариант решения:

```
stats = {}

for line in big_data_list:
    stats.setdefault(line[1], 0)
    stats[line[1]] += 1

stats
```

Все работает, но хочется узнать более оптимальный вариант кода.

Comment: В вашем варианте можно ещё использовать `defaultdict`, чтобы сократить немного цикл: from collections import defaultdict и потом stats = defaultdict(int) и тогда setdefault не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(map(lambda x: x[1],  big_data_list))
```

Результат:

```
Counter({'cpc': 4, 'none': 1, 'organic': 2})
```